# How to switch the property panel?

Tags: interface

When I finish creating an object, or select an object, I want it to automatically from other switch to the object properties panel, but i can't find the relevant interface in the panel.
[image]

Comment: but you know, that if you switch it once...and create a new one...it keeps on that tab, don't you?

Comment: Well, I just want to make the operation experience better. Is it possible

Comment: yes, might be possible with python and use as startup file ...should be possible, although i think it isn't worth the effort. You can do a lot of time savings by other things, which aren't perfect in Blender, but saving the time for one click for the day (assuming you are working only on one Blender file)

Comment: i see, thank you

Comment: the python commmand is bpy.context.space_data.context = 'OBJECT'